# Methods for solving a quadratic equation.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, quadratics, fractions

$x^2-(297+\frac{1}{297})x+1=0$.
I have a process of $x^2-(a+b)x+ab=0$. 
Provide me another method

Comment: It's special case $\,ab = 1,\ $ i.e $\ b = 1/a.\ \ $

Answer (score 3):

It's $(x-297)\left(x-\frac{1}{297}\right)=0$